# Unit testing expressjs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express

I have the following module that I'm working on adding unit tests for.  Basically I want to ensure that app.use is called with / and the appropriate handler `this.express.static('www/html')`, I also want to ensure that `app.listen` is called with the correct port.

```
function WebService(express, logger) {
    this.express = express;
    this.log = logger;
    this.port = 3000;
}

// init routes and start the server
WebService.prototype.start = function start() {    
    var app = this.express();

    // Setup routes
    app.use('/', this.express.static('www/html'));

    // Startup the server
    app.listen(this.port);

    this.log.info('Starting webserver on port %s', this.port);

};

module.exports = WebService;
```

If I remove the app.use (replace with a simple app.get) I can get the listen tested by passing this into the constructor in the unit test

```
var express_stub = function() {
                var tmpObj = {
                    get: function() {},
                    listen: listen_stub // sinonjs stub
                };
                return tmpObj;
            };
```

When I switch over to using `this.express.static` in the route, this falls over (expectedly because this.express doesn't define static)  I can't quite get my head wrapped around the correct way to deal with this. The `this.express()` as the constructor is really throwing me.  I can't figure out the correct way to mock the calls I want to validate in express.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Supertest

```
var request = require('supertest')
  , express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/user', function(req, res){
  res.send(200, { name: 'tobi' });
});

request(app)
  .get('/user')
  .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
  .expect('Content-Length', '20')
  .expect(200)
  .end(function(err, res){
if (err) throw err;
  });
```

Using Mocha:

```
describe('GET /users', function(){
  it('respond with json', function(done){
    request(app)
      .get('/user')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200, done);
  })
})
```

I suggest you to divide into two file your app: the app.js that contains all your app code and return it with module.exports, and the server.js file that requires app.js and pass it to a new http server listen method.
This way you can write tests doing require of app.js.

This is how the default app created with express generator work.

Comment: Colonnello I guess Unit Test if different from Integration Testing ... this example is an Integration test

Comment: P.M you're right. I wasn't too clear. This isn't unit testing but its the way to do testing per route, the most used in express development, but I do unit tests in express app as well, so my answer is not incorrect but incomplete I think..